# Error Installing Forecast package in R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying to install the forecast package in R Studio ( Version 1.0153) and when i try to call the package using library(forecast) i get this error

> "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘forecast’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘tibble’"

While installing the forecasting package i used the command `install.packages("forecast",dep=T)`. This is the first time i am encountering a problem when trying to install a package.

Comment: Hm, that package does not depend on tibble: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html so maybe you should try not using RStudio (which apparently inserted tibble for its own business reasons), at least for package installation.

Comment: I tried using the Console and am still getting the issue.. My R is behaving crazy after i updated from 3.3 to 3.4 and i keep getting messages where it tells me "unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\5198479\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\file3048651e4c70\forecast’ to ‘C:\Users\5198479\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\forecast’".

Answer (score 1):

I did so using this command in the console and the package was successfully installed.

```
 install.packages('forecast')
```

When using

```
 install.packages("forecast",dep=T)
```

I also received the same error as you. So will the other line do the trick?

Note I am using R 3.4 as well in the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!!! When i install the package in console and use library(forecast) in the console , the package works fine even in R studio. I guess the problem arises when we try to install the package in R studio

Comment: @m.v.Adhithya Great! Glad I could be of help. Are you all set with everything then?